# How to use Excel lookup function for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel sheets and I want to lookup a value based on two criteria, "St" and "ProductName2"

[image: Here's the first table]

[image: Here's the second table]

I want to fill PDL Status with either "P" or "NP" based on the criteria that the state columns are the same and the "ProductName2" from the first sheet matches the column in the second sheet.

How could I do this? I've tried using VLOOKUP/XLOOKUP functions but have had no luck figuring out how to implement both criteria.

Comment: Use `FILTER` as thoroughly discussed in the linked thread.